# system calls undefined! Compiling kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am new to kernel module programming, and trying to create raw socket in my kernel module using 'sys_socket'. I am binding this socket to an interface using 'sys_bind' and 'sys_ioctl' (for fetching interface number).

While compiling my module, I get the following errors:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-68-generic/build M=/root/Kernel_Module modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-68-generic'
CC [M]  /root/Kernel_Module/kernel_module.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "sys_ioctl" [/root/Kernel_Module/kernel_module.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_bind" [/root/Kernel_Module/kernel_module.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "sys_socket" [/root/Kernel_Module/kernel_module.ko] undefined!
CC      /root/Kernel_Module/kernel_module.mod.o
LD [M]  /root/Kernel_Module/kernel_module.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-68-generic'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

The code is specified below:

```
struct sockaddr_ll socketBindAddr;
struct ifreq       ifreq;
int                socketFd = 0;

socketFd = sys_socket (AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
if (socketFd < 0)
{
    printk (KERN_CRIT "Failed to open data socket!!\r\n");
    return OFC_FAILURE;
}

memset (&ifreq, 0, sizeof(ifreq));
strcpy (ifreq.ifr_name, gOfcGlobals.aDataIfName);
if (sys_ioctl (socketFd, SIOCGIFINDEX, (unsigned long) &ifreq) < 0)
{
    printk (KERN_CRIT "Ioctl failed to get IfIndex!!\r\n");
    return OFC_FAILURE;
}

memset (&socketBindAddr, 0, sizeof(socketBindAddr));
socketBindAddr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
socketBindAddr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
if (sys_bind (socketFd, (struct sockaddr *) &socketBindAddr,
    sizeof(socketBindAddr)) < 0)
{
    printk (KERN_CRIT "Failed to bind socket\r\n");
    return OFC_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: In short: Syscalls are for **user-space programs**, not for *kernel modules*. Some syscalls have analogues for in-kernel use. I don't know about in-kernel analogues for `ioctl`, `bind` and `socket`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys_bind()` and `sys_ioctl` (and `sys_socket`) are the (low-level) **user-space** interface to the kernel.  You haven't shown us the code you've written, but you'll need to use a more suitable kernel-internal interface for your net access.

Comment: Added code. Kindly suggest if a procedure to create sockets using kernel module.

Comment: Sorry, I've never done high-level networking in a kernel module.  I had a look at NFS to see how it opens connections, but got lost - perhaps NBD is a simpler starting point?  Try reading `/drivers/block/nbd.c`, perhaps.

Comment: Sockets can be created in the kernel using the following functions:

sock_create()               /* Create Socket */
sock->ops->bind ()       /* Bind Socket */
sock->ops->release ()  /* Close Socket */

struct socket is the structure for sockets in kernel, instead of file descriptors in user space.